# Platform.sh email sending with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, email, sendmail, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send emails from my Symfony 3 project at Platform.sh.

I followed this documentation: [https://docs.platform.sh/administration/web/email.html](http://I%20followed%20this%20documentation:%20https://docs.platform.sh/administration/web/email.html)

My parameters.yml:

```
mailer_transport: sendmail
mailer_host: null
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
mailer_port: 465
mailer_encryption: tls
```

I use swiftmailer with memory spooling. Swiftmailer's `send()` method returns true, but it seems like it doesn't relly send any emails.

In the settings, outgoing emails are ON for Master.

Do I need to set any system variables, or what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Using the Drupal Symfony Mailer module on a Drupal 9 or 10 website I had to override the sendmail transport command to use the `-t` option instead of the default `-bs`.  Note that [Sendmail documentation](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/baselib-sendmail-1.html) recommends using the `-i` or `-oi` options any time you use the `-t` option.

```php
// sites/default/settings.platformsh.php

// Required for Sendgrid (via msmtp intercept from sendmail) on Platform.sh.
$config['symfony_mailer.mailer_transport.sendmail']['configuration']['query']['command'] = ini_get('sendmail_path') . ' -t -i';
```

For the (now deprecated) SwiftMailer for Drupal 8/9, you must set the `transport_mode` to 't' instead of 'bs'

```yaml
# swiftmailer.transport.yml
sendmail_mode: 't'
```

Another possibility is to use platformsh environment variables.

`d8config:swiftmailer.transport:sendmail_mode`
and set its value to 't'

Hopefully it could help you on Symfony too.